# ReactJS deploy on GitHub

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my ReactJS on GitHub Pages usin `gh-pages` as recommended in React readme. However, it looks like the path works in a bit wrong way. No images are loaded. Router tries to refer to `username.github.io` instead of `username.github.io/app`.

So, when I open my site https://gultyaev.github.io/test-task/ error 404 is shown. When I navigate to `How it works` route changes to `https://gultyaev.github.io/`.

The `homepage` in `package.json` is set.

Images in project are initially placed in `public` and referred as `/Images/image.svg`.

Package json link https://github.com/gultyaev/test-task/blob/master/package.json

Comment: The `homepage` property is no longer set. If you still need help on this please update your question.

Comment: Solved by deploying on heroku.